# stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: is not removing characters in the middle of the string

Tags: objective-c, string, nsstring, nscharacterset

I want to remove "#" from my string.

I have tried

```
 NSString *abc = [@"A#BCD#D" stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"#"]];
```

But it still shows the string as "A#BCD#D"

What could be wrong?

Comment: If you're looking for a one liner that can remove more than one character (you mentioned `NSCharacterSet`s, after all), see my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26152034/901641

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could try

```
NSString *modifiedString = [yourString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"#" withString:@""];
```

Answer (score 56):

`stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet` removes characters from the beginning and end of your string, not from any place in it

For your purpose use `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:` method as others pointed.

Comment: Then why the heck isn't it called "stringByTrimmingCharactersInSetJustFromTheVeryEndOrVeryBeginning"...

Comment: I guess trim implies that, but I am not a native english speaker :)

Answer (score 15):

I wrote a category of `NSString` for that:

```
- (NSString *)stringByReplaceCharacterSet:(NSCharacterSet *)characterset withString:(NSString *)string {
    NSString *result = self;
    NSRange range = [result rangeOfCharacterFromSet:characterset];

    while (range.location != NSNotFound) {
        result = [result stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
        range = [result rangeOfCharacterFromSet:characterset];
    }
    return result;
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
NSCharacterSet *funnyCharset = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"#"];
NSString *newString = [string stringByReplaceCharacterSet:funnyCharset withString:@""];
```

Comment: +1, although I dislike the redundancy caused by using a `while` loop, so I wrote a method which uses recursion instead (`do-while` probably could have also removed the redundancies): http://stackoverflow.com/a/26152034/901641

Answer (score 11):

I previously had a relatively complicated recursive answer for this (see edit history of this answer if you'd like to see that answer), but then I found a pretty simple one liner:

```
- (NSString *)stringByRemovingCharactersInSet:(NSCharacterSet *)characterSet {
    return [[self componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:characterSet] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
}
```

Comment: took me quite a while to figure why xcode wasn't accepting it :) thanks for the answer by the way.

Answer (score 3):

Refer to the Apple Documentation about: [stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: method in NSString](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-SW6)

```
NSString *str1=[str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"#" withString:@""];
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Use below

```
NSString * myString = @"A#BCD#D";
NSString * newString = [myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"#" withString:@""];
```