# characterSetWithCharactersInString not working

Tags: string, trim

#### Code:

```
NSString *str = @"ABC\rDEF";

str = [str stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
        [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"\r"]];
NSLog(@"%s", [str UTF8String]);
```

#### Result

```
ABC
DEF
```

Answer (score 3):

Check the `NSString` class reference reference for `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:`:

> Returns a new string made by removing from both ends of the receiver characters contained in a given character set.

Since the `\r` occurs in the middle of the string, noting happens.

Answer (score 0):

Anne answer is correct trimming will not impact a character that is not at the beginning or end of a string. You want to do a replace of all occurrences of \r, so you should use `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString`

Here is another answer that covers this problem:
[stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: is not removing characters in the middle of the string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5581141/stringbytrimmingcharactersinset-is-not-working)